# Firebase - upload/delete best practice? Should you daisy chain the upload/delete steps?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am just wondering what is the best practice when handling upload and deleting of firebase database and storage.

So for example, I have images uploaded into the storage, and I have extra informations that are uploaded into the database that points to the images in the storage.

So currently, when I upload an image, this is the logic process I go through.

1. upload image to storage

   - If fail: let user know.
   - If success: step 2.
2. upload image info to database

   - If fail: let user know + delete previous image from storage.
   - If success: step 3.
3. upload image location into geofire database

   - If fail: let user know + delete image info from database, delete image from storage.
   - If success: let user know.

So as you can see, I am doing this daisy chain kind of upload, where the next upload only occurs if the previous is successful. And if one step of the upload have failed, I will run codes to revert/delete the uploads I just made.

My delete mechanism is pretty much the exact opposite to my upload. Delete  1 step at a time, and if one step fails, go back and revert/upload the previous data again.

I am just wondering if this sort of protection mechanism is necessary? Or do most people just run all upload and download simultaneously? Such as:
- upload image to storage.
- upload image info to database.
- upload image location to geofire.

Thank you!

Comment: You can do a single image upload, attach metadata to it, then have a Cloud Function automatically trigger to copy that metadata wherever it needs to be.

Comment: Thank you. Reading through the docs, it says "This metadata contains typical file metadata properties such as name, size, and contentType". So does that mean I can't attach additional custom data to it, such as location data? Since I need to pass these to geofire as well.

Comment: You can put whatever strings you want in there.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/metadata

Comment: Ah thank you! Really appreciated you help!

Comment: @DougStevenson sorry to bother you again. I just noticed that to attach the metadata to the image, you do "putBytes(mByteArray, metadata)" But how am I able to attache the imageDownloadUrl to the metadata if I can only get the url after image is uploaded? I need to attach the download url, since I need to pass that to my database, so user can see the image in a recyclerview.

Comment: It sounds like you have a second question to ask here on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I will go do that. Again, thank you for your help!